# BigQuery - how to list all user defined functions (UDFs)

Tags: java, google-bigquery

How can I list all the user defined functions in BigQuery programmatically e.g in Java or SQL?

Comment: This could help  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8):

You can list UDFs ("routines") using the `bq` command line tool:

```
bq ls --routines '<project_name>:<dataset_id>'
```

You can the same command-line tool to get information about the UDF's argument and return value:

```
bq show --routine '<project_name>:<dataset_id>.<udf_name>'
```

If you need the actual code of the UDF, or if you don't have access to the `bq` utility, you can also query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
 select * 
  from `<project_name>.<dataset_name>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES`;
```

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery UDFs must be specified for each query. There is nowhere to list them from since you are responsible for storing them and specifying them for each query you want to use them in.

For more information on UDFs, please see:
-Legacy SQL UDFs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions
-Standard SQL UDFs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions